# How to get subsection for each section in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, get, rendering

I'm trying to display subSections for each sections in the frontend but not sure how to do that so I will be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

*I have two table section and subsection in my database.*

*Section table have Id, and Section Name.*

*Subsection table have Id, ParentId(forigen key to Section table Id), Subsection Name and Text.*

In my frontend http service I have two get methods (one for section and another one for subsection)

Services.ts

```
  getHelpSection() {
    return this.http.get<HelpSection[]>(`${environment.api.chart}/helpSection`).pipe(first());
  }
  getHelpSubsection() {
    return this.http.get<SubSection[]>(`${environment.api.chart}/helpSubsection`).pipe(first());
  }
```

Component.ts

```
Constructor(private HelpService: HelpService) {}
  helpSection: {[key: string]: HelpSection } = {};

  helpSection$ = this.HelpService.getHelpSection();
  helpSubsection$ = this.HelpService.getHelpSubsection();
```

Component.html

```
<mat-nav-list>
   <mat-expansion-panel class="exp-panel" *ngFor= "let help of helpSection$ | async">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header style="align-items: center;">
    <div >{{help.sectionName}}</div>
   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <a mat-list-item (click)="clicked()">Here it will display subSection Name for each sections</a>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Right now it look like this.

[image: Right now it look like this]

Answer (score 0):

this.HelpService.getHelpSection().subscribe(res => { this.helpSection$ = res });

Comment: I'm not sure about this, can you explain more.. thx

Comment: you created a observable and for get response from observable should use a subscribe